# LINQ - Union current and previous data to one row

Tags: c#, linq, union

I have the task: show in one row data for current and previous period

For example:

Seller: XXX

Currency: EUR

Period: 01.2018

Total count: 4

Total amount: 40.00

Previous total count: 3

Previous total amount: 30.00

I created according class with all necessary fields and I have wrote two requests with different dates.
In the first request I fill fields **Total count** & **Total amount**. In other - **Previous total count** & **Previous total amount**

How I can union the relevant rows (for example - 01.2018 & 01.2017) in one row?

I wrote the following comparer:

```
class MyDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyData>
{
    public bool Equals(MyData x, MyData y)
    {
        return x.Seller == y.Seller && x.Currency == y.Currency && x.Month == y.Month && x.Year -1 == y.Year;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyData myModel)
    {
        return myModel.Seller.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use it as

> var result = currentPeriod.Union(previousPeriod, new myDataComparer());

But it not accumulate the relevant data in one row.
It just added rows from previous period to the current period' rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a join, not union . Alternativly , create a ViewModel with the extra fields, and manually intialize them

Comment: It's not clear what the desired result is, what means `Union`? You want to merge these rows by summing the counts? Then i wonder why you think that it works this way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think he just want to attach these two columns into `currentPeriod` object ..

Comment: Yes, I want to see data from columns "Previous total count" & "Previous total amount" in relevant row for current period

Comment: Is [that](http://www.herlitz.nu/2011/12/01/getting-the-previous-and-next-record-from-list-using-linq/) helping ? Can you get the current row first or you want to enumarate and yeild the matching and the previous of each matching?

Comment: Do you know what `Union` does? Have you looked at the documentation?